# How do I reload a python module?

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-module, python-3.9

This has been asked 1000 times before, but nothing seems to work for me.

Using Python3.9 and VScode, though I have tested it making edits with just the plain TextEdit app on mac as well.

I cloned this repository: https://github.com/trevorbayless/cli-chess, and I would like to customize it.

I run it via the terminal: $ python3 .../__main__.py

everything works. below is the contents of __main__.py

```
from cli_chess.core.main import MainModel, MainPresenter

def main() -> None:
    """Main entry point"""
    MainPresenter(MainModel()).run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I open the project in VScode, make a change to a file in the source code, and the change is not reflected. Only changes to __main__.py are reflected. I can move __main__.py to another directory and run the program without issue. I can even delete every project file other than __main__.py from my computer, and still run the program as if I didn't touch a thing.

This still doesn't make a lot of sense to me, but from what I understand, this is due to how modules are handled in Python, and I need to reload them. I can't get this to work.

I've tried using importlib like below, and other variations. Nothing seems to make a difference.

```
import cli_chess.core.main
import importlib
importlib.reload(cli_chess.core.main)
from cli_chess.core.main import MainModel, MainPresenter

def main() -> None:
    """Main entry point"""
    MainPresenter(MainModel()).run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I've also seen these commands floating around:

```
%reload_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

I don't understand how to utilize this. "Just add it to your code" gives me syntax errors.

Other folks have suggested restarting VScode. I quit, I reopen, nothing changes. I'm surely missing something obvious, right? It's kind of blowing my mind how difficult it is to throw some print statements into a fairly basic python project.

Props to trevorbayless by the way, very cool chess app.

Answer (score 1):

To "reload" a module, you can just delete the module object and then import it again. Like this:

```
del module_name
import module_name
```

Although I don't really suggest it. There's probably a better solution to fix your problem, but if you really wanted to "reload" a module, this is a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by finding where the module actually lives on my computer, and editing that instead of the source code in the project. The import statement in **main**.py was never pointing to the files in the project folder

My situation was probably overly convoluted. I downloaded and tested a 'release' before downloading the source code. My thinking is that the original executable from the release put the cli-chess module in my python site-packages, and the source code I downloaded later referenced that by default, instead of itself.

I used this code to find the path to the module on my computer, modules are in in the site-packages directory.

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

So I think the reloading probably worked, I was just editing the wrong files. Thanks all